# VBA: "Comparemode" error in empty dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

When this code runs:

```
        Dim dic As Object
        .            
        .     
        .     
        If dic Is Nothing Then
            Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            dic.comparemode = 1 
        Else
            dic.RemoveAll
        End If
```

At the `comparemode` line, I occasionally get the

> Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

As I understand it, I would get the error if the dictionary had data in it, but as you can see it didn't even exist until the previous line.

Comment: Are there any more specific details you can give around when this occurs? i.e. how do we reproduce the error?

Comment: If it happens only "occasionally", then something else in your code (the you didn't post here) is causing the issue, because the code you posted works perfectly fine for me.